# How create universal fetcher for all requests in client and server(getInitialProps)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i write this helper to my api directions folder, and i use token from browser cookie

```
import 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import { API } from './api_url';

export default async function sendRequest(path, opts = {}) {
    const headers = Object.assign({}, opts.headers || {}, {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': cookie.get('token') // from browser 'js-cookie'
    });

    const response = await fetch(
        `${API}${path}`,
        Object.assign({ method: 'POST', credentials: 'same-origin' }, opts, {
            headers
        })
    );

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.error) {
        throw new Error(data.error);
    }

    return data;
}
```

example use in api folders

```
const BASE_PATH = '/v1';

export const getCats = () =>
    sendRequest(`${BASE_PATH}/breeds`, {
        method: 'GET'
    });
```

but i don t use my fetcher in getInitialprops, because cookies get it of nextCookie(ctx)

```
Index.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    const { token } = nextCookie(ctx)
    const cats = await getCats(); //'Authorization' :undefined because cookie.get('token') => undefined
    return { cats } ;
};
```

how create or beatify implement this code and result something like this

```
export default async function sendRequest(path, opts = {}) {
    const headers = Object.assign({}, opts.headers || {}, {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': getTokenFromClientOrServer()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `nextCookie` method comes from using [next-cookies](https://github.com/matthewmueller/next-cookies) npm package. In the package documentation it is stated that it works both client and server side:

> Tiny little function for getting cookies on both client & server with next.js.

In your `Index` component you are already using the `nextCookie` method to retrieve the value of `token` cookie, but you are not using it:

```
const { token } = nextCookie(ctx);
```

If you want to have a method `getTokenFromClientOrServer` to retrieve the cookie in both server and client side, you will have to pass the context `ctx` parameter:

```
function getTokenFromClientOrServer(ctx) {
    return nextCookie(ctx).token;
}
```